# Chamar função dentro de outra

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código

```js
 function nomes() {

     function funcao() {
         alert("teste");


     }

       function funcao2() {
         alert("teste2");
     }

 }
```

```html
<input class="todas" id="checkall" type="checkbox" onclick="funcao2();">
```

Ao tentar executar a função 2 atraves da checkbox acontece o seguinte erro:
**funcao2 is not defined**

Qual a maneira correta de chamar essa função ?

Comment: Removi minha resposta porque ela só funcionava se declarar as funções de outro jeito e não do jeito que está seu código (por isso funcionou nos meus testes). Antes de colocar outra resposta, queria saber qual é a sua intenção colocando uma função dentro da outra. Do jeito que está aí, essas funções internas só são acessíveis dentro do objeto `nomes()`, mesmo se você fizesse `nomes.funcao2`.

Comment: Porque não colocar as funções todas em separado em vez de dentro da função `nomes()` ? O que está exatamente a tentar fazer?

Comment: Achei melhor fazer isso mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema que encontrou é devido ao escopo da função. Você somente poderá acessar a funcao2 depois que acessar a nome, pelo fato da primeira estar aninhada à segunda. Para isso ela precisa estar vinculada a um objeto fora da função.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function nomes() {

     this.chamada1 = function funcao() {
         alert("teste");
     }

     this.chamada2 = function funcao2() {
         alert("teste2");
     }
 }  

 var fChamada = new nomes();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="todas" id="checkall" type="checkbox" onclick="fChamada.chamada2();">
</body>
</html>
```

A solução acima funciona, porém, há várias maneiras diferentes de fazê-lo dependendo do objetivo que você pretende atingir.

:)